# How to remove the white background that appears upon hiding the drop-down menu in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using **Bootstrap 3.3.4**

I've following HTML code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="projects" class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle projects" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="projects">Projects</span></a>
          <ul id="projects-menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/prj/pages/project/projectList.html">List</a></li>
            <li><a href="/prj/pages/project/createNewProject.html">Add new project</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Now using jQuery I'm hiding the sub-menus coming under main-menu **'Projects'** as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul#projects-menu").children().hide();
});
```

The menu gets hide but a small white background appears beneath the menu which I don't want. For better understanding of my issue please refer below image. In this image you can see the white background appearing beneath the **'Projects'** menu.

[image: See the white background appearing beneath the 'Projects' menu]

Can someone please help me in this regard?

Thanks.

Comment: if you are hiding sub menu you need to hide parent of that child. just remove .children() from Jquey will solve issue

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul#projects-menu").hide();
});
```

hide the meniu not the li's

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#projects-menu > li > a').on('click', function() {  
    $(this).children('#projects-menu').hide();
});
```

**also you can like this**

```
$(this).find("#projects-menu > li").hide();
```